# ravendb index, query on child collection

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I want to get a summary of all products, as only the latest OrderHistory is of interest where I want to use this. I have thousands of products with hundreds of OrderHistory each, but now I only want the product id and the latest OrderHistory for each product.

```
public class ProductSummary
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public OrderHistory LastOrderHistory { get; set; }
}
```

The OrderHistory is stored inside the Product document like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MarketGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<OrderHistory> OrderHistory { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what OrderHistory looks like:

```
public class OrderHistory
    {
        public long OrderCount { get; set; }
        public long Volume { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public double AvgPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I've tried a few approaches on the index and query to get this running, this is my latest try, but it returns no results.

```
public class LatestProductOrderHistory : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Product, ProductSummary>
{
    public LatestProductOrderHistory()
    {
        Map = products => from p in products
                          from oh in p.OrderHistory
            select new
            {
                ProductId = p.Id,
                LastOrderHIstory = p.OrderHistory.OrderByDescending(o => o.date).Last()
            };

        StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

And finally my query:

```
                var results = session
                    .Query<ProductSummary, LatestProductOrderHistory>()
                    .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<ProductSummary>()
                    .Take(1024)
                    .Skip(start)
                    .ToList();
```

This combination gives me no results, I have never made indexes in ravendb before, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

**EDIT:** Well, I'm not sure what I changed, but now I'm getting "Could not read value for property: Id"
**EDIT2:** The strange issue in previous edit was solved by restarting vs and ravendb, so current result is no result

Comment: You need to do this with a map/reduce index

Comment: Thanks! I ended up moving the orderhistory out of the products too.

Answer (score 0):

As Ayende commented, you must add the Reduce function to your index as:

```
Reduce = results => from result in results
    group result by result.Id into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        LastOrderHistory = g.SelectMany(x=> x.LastOrderHistory)
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).FirstOrDefault()
        };
```

Just selecting wanted fields in Map function **does not** make your index Map/Reduce.

Then query your index as:

```
session.Query<ProductSummary, LatestProductOrderHistory>()
```